# Is it possible to have a Calendar per team?

Tags: calendar

Is it possible to have a Calendar only for particular team where the members of that team to be able to input information on events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in **Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, and Developer** editions

- View and edit your existing public calendars and resource calendars.
  From Setup, enter Public Calendars and Resources in the Quick Find
  box, then select Public Calendars and Resources.
- Create a public
  calendar or a resource calendar.

From here it is a matter of managing access to each calendar, typically to be done using public groups or roles. Click `Sharing` from either page you'll visit using the instructions above.

[Further information on setup and sharing of public calendars can be found here.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_groupcal.htm&language=en_US&type=0)